# Verificar campo de cadastro

Tags: php, html

Tem alguma forma de obrigar no meu formulario de cadastro utilizar somente o gmail?

```
            if(filter_var($post_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            if(strlen($post_password) >= 8){
                if(!preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{ @#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $post_login)){
                    if(!player_exist_login($post_login) && !player_exist_email2($post_email)){
                        if(player_create($post_login,$post_email,$post_password,$post_chardeletecode)){
                            if(player_send_email_register($post_login,$post_email,$post_password,$post_chardeletecode)){
                                promo_code($promocode);
                                r('verify/');
                            }else{
                                $check_msg = l(170);
                            }
                        }else{
                            $check_msg = l(84);
                        }
                    }else{
                        $check_msg = l(83);
                    }
                }else{
                    $check_msg = l(81);
                }
            }else{
                $check_msg = l(80);
            }
        }else{
            $check_msg = l(79);
        }
```

Comment: Você pode usar a função `includes` do JS para verificar se a substring `@gmail.com` existe dentro da string que guarda o valor do email...

Comment: Se é só gmail, por que deixa o usuário preencher? Não seria mais simples fazer o input ANTES do dominio? `[campo input]@gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

Use um padrão de expressão regular:

> "/@gmail.com$/i"

Na prática:

```
<?php
if (!preg_match("/@gmail\.com$/i", $endereco_email))
{
// Nao tem @gmail.com
}
?>
```

Saiba mais sobre [expressões regulares](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php).

Não sei onde quer que o e-mail seja testado, mas inseri ele dentro da função de envio, confira:

```
<?php
function player_create($a,$b,$c,$d){
 return true;
}
function player_exist_login($a){
 return true;
}
function l($a){
 return true;
}

if(player_send_email_register("asdasdasdasdasdasdasd","teste1@gmail.com","asdasdasdasdasdasdasd","UTF-8")){

  if (!preg_match("/@gmail\.com$/i", "teste1@gmail.com"))
  {
    echo "nao tem";
    exit();
  }
    else {
    echo "tem";
  }

}
```

?>

Comment: Para verificar FINAL da string: `substr($string, -<tamanho da substring>) == <substring>`

Comment: regex somente né?

Comment: Isso dá verdadeiro: `strpos("email@gmail.com.batata","@gmail.com")`

Comment: '|^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@gmail\.com$|i' é o que consigo, confere?

Comment: A regex nao é o problema, a versão com strpos só, acredito eu.

Comment: Edite a verificação como na resposta e veja se fica bom para você, a expressão que usa está suja com regra desnecessária.

Comment: Elisei eu atualizei o post com o meu codigo php poderia verificar por gentileza.

Comment: Infelizmente não resultou e para não prolongarmos muito isso coloquei no pastebin para você entender a minha bagunça.. me perdoe.. https://pastebin.com/m5cfTGb5 no paste bin procure por: Register User já agraço a presteza.

Comment: Reduza o seu código, deixe apenas a parte onde a verificação deve ser feita, será mais prático e fácil para finalizar seu post.